# Как поместить один Фрагмент в два разных действия?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Всем привет!

Помогите с вопросом.

Я сделал Navigation Drawer Activity и TabsLayout. У TabsLayout сделал два Фрагмента.
В Navigation Drawer есть менюшка. Так вот я хочу, чтобы первый пункт менюшки вызывал первый Фрагмент TabsLayout. Говоря простым языком = У меня будет на главной странице приложения вкладки: "История"(Фрагмент#1) и Описание(Фрагмент#2). В меню Navigation Drawer первая строка также называется "История" и вот она должна при нажатии открывать (Фрагмент#1).

Я почитал про фрагменты и вроде, что-то там есть похожее, но никак не могу сообразить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фрагмент в Activity создается примерно так:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container, new YourFragment())
    .commit()
```

Чтоб использовать 1 фрагмент в разных Активити просто создайте разные экземпляры этого класса в каждом активити. Если фрагменты должны иметь разные входные параметры для каждой активити - используйте Bundle чтоб передать аргументы.

Вот [тут](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html) есть серия уроков по фрагментам

Comment: Sergei Buvaka, спасибо!